# ProcessPoolExecutor with Monte Carlo simulations

Tags: python

I have a question about using ProcessPoolExecutor to calculate pi,
this is the function provided by my teacher

```
def myth_value(n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(n):
        x = random()
        y = random()
        if x * x + y * y < 1:
            count += 1
    return count / n * 4
```

and this is my code to execute this function with ProcessPoolExecutor:

```
start_time =  timeit.default_timer()
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    size = simulations // concurrency
    result = sum(executor.map(myth_value, [size] * concurrency))/ concurrency # each process return pi, sum(pi)/total_process = avg pi
end_time = timeit.default_timer()
```

in this case, I am calculating avg pi, and I am not sure should I modify the function to just return count, sum up the count then do sum(count)/n*4 to calculate the pi?

Comment: What were the instructions that your teacher gave you?

Comment: "performs Monte Carlo simulations to calculate the value of " that it.
However, in this function each process already return Monte Carlo simulations.(value of pi)...